# How to fix 'paytm payment webview reload and failed response' error in android and ios

Tags: paytm

I am using android and ios webview for paytm. My api is in PHP.

1. When payment button clicked paytm load its payment screen.
2. then i choose debit card.
3. On entering debit card number web-view automatically  reload and empty response get in callback url

I found paytm response "RESPCODE":"2023","RESPMSG":"Repeat Request Inconsistent",

Answer (score 0):

Try using paytm login instead of net banking or card payment.